# Understanding why List<string> is changed like it was passed as an reference C#

Tags: c#, list

Maybe someone can help me, I'm really stumped.

I have a class called TextFunc which contains 2 functions.

The first function read a filepath and return a `List<string>`.

The second function takes that `List<string>` as a argument and returns an `float[,]`. Within this function I remove the first item of the list since I'm not interested in the header.

My problem is that somehow my second function modifies the original List.

So If I display the the first item of the list before the second function it shows what I expect.

After the second function the first item is gone.

I can't figure out why since I'm not using a reference when passing the argument into the second function. I don't even call it the same name or anything within the second function.

My class containing the 2 functions look like this (only keeping the relevant parts):

```
    class TextFunc
{

    public static List<string> ParseText(string filePath)
    {

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

        //do some stuff

        return lines;
    }



    public static float[,] txt2Array(List<string> txtList)
    {
        
        txtList.RemoveAt(0);

        // do some stuff
        return floatArray;
    }
}
```

I call the functions like this from an buttonclick event inside the Form1.cs

```
    public partial class BRkData : Form
{
    public BRkData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void BRkData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> txtFile = TextFunc.ParseText(@"C:\org_data.res");
        MessageBox.Show(txtFile[0]); // here it displays what I expect
        float[,] floatArr = TextFunc.txt2Array(txtFile);
        MessageBox.Show(txtFile[0]); // here the first item of the list is gone?        
    }

}
```

I even tried making a copy of the list inside the txt2Array function but it does not matter. Somehow it's like I send a reference to the list to this function without knowing it.

Comment: `List<string> txtList` *is*  a reference to the object. When you call a method on that object it will potentially modify that one, since there is no copy of it.

Comment: Because `List<T>` is a class and is therefore a reference type, so when you pass it to a method you are creating another reference to the same object, not creating a copy of that object.

Comment: @Liam - `string` isn't a value type. It's an immutable reference type

Comment: @UnholySheep there's no _potential_ about it; that object _will_ be modified.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yes, bad phrasing on my part - I wanted to somehow indicate that not all methods modify an object's internal state

Comment: Ok thanks veryone, I tried copying in but didnät use the .ToList() function. i.e. List<string> txtList = txtList_org.ToList();

Comment: @UnholySheep Ok, it's just that if OP is learning about reference vs value types that could be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this. There is a man called List (reference type object) who knows a list of good pubs. You have his phone number on a piece of paper.

Calling a method is like giving the phone number to someone else. They have it written on a different bit of paper, but the same man answers the phone.

Passing using the ref keyword would mean that you give the other person the **same bit of paper**. They could cross out the original phone number and put a new one in, and give it back to you.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know I had to use the ToList command when I tried to copy it inside the function.

`List<string> txtList = txtList_org.ToList();`

Thank you for clarifying and pointing me in the right direction!